# How to improve efficiency of query by removing sub-query producing field?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables and sample data:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hxQ7BGdgDJtQcv5xTChY9u/0

I would like to increase the performance of the contained query in db-fiddle by ideally removing the sub-query producing the `success` field (this was taken from ChatGPT output, but it was unable to remove this sub-query without destroying the results). How can I do this?

My question to ChatGPT was this:

> using the tables in `<db-fiddle link>`, write a select sql query to
> return all cfg_commissioning_tags columns and
> dat_commissioning_test_log.success. These tables are joined by
> cfg_commissioning_tags.id = dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id. If the
> tag_source is 'plc' and any rows have success = true, return true for
> the success field for all matching type_id and relative_tag_path rows.

To the result ChatGPT produced, I added the  `AND ct_2.device_name != ct_1.device_name` condition into the sub-query which is also required.

The current query, table creation queries, and the current query results are all copied below for posterity:

```
SELECT
    ct_1.device_parent_path
    ,ct_1.device_name
    ,ct_1.relative_tag_path
    ,ct_1.tag_source
    ,ct_1.type_id
  ,CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_2
      JOIN cfg_commissioning_tags ct_2 ON ct_2.id = ctl_2.tag_id
      WHERE
        ct_2.type_id = ct_1.type_id
        AND ct_2.relative_tag_path = ct_1.relative_tag_path
        AND ct_2.device_name != ct_1.device_name -- without this, it runs super fast, but I need this
        AND ctl_2.success = TRUE
        AND ct_2.tag_source = 'plc'
    ) THEN 'true*'
    ELSE CASE ctl_1.success WHEN true THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
  END AS success
FROM cfg_commissioning_tags ct_1
LEFT JOIN dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_1 ON ct_1.id = ctl_1.tag_id
ORDER BY type_id, relative_tag_path
```

```
CREATE TABLE dat_commissioning_test_log
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    tag_id integer,
    -- tested_on timestamp with time zone,
    success boolean,
    -- username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    -- note character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT dat_commissioning_test_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE cfg_commissioning_tags
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    -- full_path character varying(400) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    device_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    device_parent_path character varying(400) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    -- added_on timestamp with time zone,
    relative_tag_path character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    -- retired_on timestamp with time zone,
    tag_source character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type_id character varying(400) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT cfg_commissioning_tags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO cfg_commissioning_tags (id, device_name, device_parent_path, relative_tag_path, tag_source, type_id) VALUES
(1, 'PC13A','DUMMY','Run Mins','plc','DOL'),
(2, 'PC12A','DUMMY','Run Mins','plc','DOL'),
(3, 'PC11A','DUMMY','Run Mins','plc','DOL'),
(4, 'PC11A','DUMMY','Status','io','DOL'),
(5, 'PC11A','DUMMY','Alarms/Isolator Tripped','io','DOL'),
(6, 'PC12A','DUMMY','Status','io','DOL');

INSERT INTO dat_commissioning_test_log (tag_id, success) VALUES
(1, true),
(6, true);
```

This is the results of the query:

| device_parent_path | device_name | relative_tag_path | tag_source | type_id | success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DUMMY | PC11A | Alarms/Isolator Tripped | io | DOL | FALSE |
| DUMMY | PC13A | Run Mins | plc | DOL | TRUE |
| DUMMY | PC12A | Run Mins | plc | DOL | true* |
| DUMMY | PC11A | Run Mins | plc | DOL | true* |
| DUMMY | PC12A | Status | io | DOL | TRUE |
| DUMMY | PC11A | Status | io | DOL | FALSE |

**Edit:**
Here is the `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` result:

```
"Sort  (cost=4368188.41..4368208.24 rows=7932 width=188) (actual time=10378.617..10378.916 rows=8108 loops=1)"
"  Output: ct_1.id, ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.added_on, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.retired_on, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, (CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE ctl_1.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END)"
"  Sort Key: ct_1.type_id, ct_1.relative_tag_path"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2350kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=2895186"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=60.69..4367674.67 rows=7932 width=188) (actual time=1.991..10357.671 rows=8108 loops=1)"
"        Output: ct_1.id, ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.added_on, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.retired_on, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE ctl_1.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END"
"        Hash Cond: (ct_1.id = ctl_1.tag_id)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2895186"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_1  (cost=0.00..426.32 rows=7932 width=156) (actual time=0.013..1.313 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"              Output: ct_1.id, ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.added_on, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.retired_on, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=347"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=40.86..40.86 rows=1586 width=5) (actual time=0.326..0.326 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"              Output: ctl_1.success, ctl_1.tag_id"
"              Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 79kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=25"
"              ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_1  (cost=0.00..40.86 rows=1586 width=5) (actual time=0.012..0.171 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"                    Output: ctl_1.success, ctl_1.tag_id"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=25"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Hash Join  (cost=505.71..550.57 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.267..1.267 rows=0 loops=8108)"
"                Inner Unique: true"
"                Hash Cond: (ctl_2.tag_id = ct_2.id)"
"                Buffers: shared hit=2894814"
"                ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_2  (cost=0.00..40.86 rows=1521 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.112 rows=1300 loops=3800)"
"                      Output: ctl_2.id, ctl_2.tag_id, ctl_2.tested_on, ctl_2.success, ctl_2.username, ctl_2.note"
"                      Filter: ctl_2.success"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 56"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=81338"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=505.64..505.64 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=1.183..1.183 rows=98 loops=8108)"
"                      Output: ct_2.id"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=2813476"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_2  (cost=0.00..505.64 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.620..1.169 rows=98 loops=8108)"
"                            Output: ct_2.id"
"                            Filter: (((ct_2.device_name)::text <> (ct_1.device_name)::text) AND ((ct_2.type_id)::text = (ct_1.type_id)::text) AND ((ct_2.relative_tag_path)::text = (ct_1.relative_tag_path)::text) AND ((ct_2.tag_source)::text = 'plc'::text))"
"                            Rows Removed by Filter: 7834"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=2813476"
"Planning Time: 0.382 ms"
"Execution Time: 10379.346 ms"
```

**Edit 2**
EXPLAIN after adding compound indexes:

```
"Sort  (cost=540847.20..540867.03 rows=7932 width=198) (actual time=1142.282..1142.843 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"  Output: ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, (CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE dat_commissioning_test_log.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END)"
"  Sort Key: ct_1.full_path"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2290kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=778254"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=149.19..540333.47 rows=7932 width=198) (actual time=1.775..1108.469 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"        Output: ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE dat_commissioning_test_log.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END"
"        Hash Cond: (ct_1.id = dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=778254"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_1  (cost=0.00..426.32 rows=7932 width=140) (actual time=0.011..0.837 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"              Output: ct_1.id, ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.added_on, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.retired_on, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=347"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=139.24..139.24 rows=796 width=35) (actual time=1.404..1.404 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"              Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id"
"              Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 83kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=50"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=85.28..139.24 rows=796 width=35) (actual time=0.938..1.249 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                    Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Hash Cond: (dat_commissioning_test_log.id = "ANY_subquery".max)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=50"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1593 width=39) (actual time=0.009..0.089 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"                          Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.username, dat_commissioning_test_log.note"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=82.78..82.78 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.926..0.926 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                          Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                          Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 66kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=80.78..82.78 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.710..0.804 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                Group Key: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=48.90..77.23 rows=1417 width=4) (actual time=0.297..0.475 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                      Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=48.90..63.07 rows=1417 width=8) (actual time=0.297..0.413 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: max(dat_commissioning_test_log_1.id), dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id"
"                                            Group Key: dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log dat_commissioning_test_log_1  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1593 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.090 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"                                                  Output: dat_commissioning_test_log_1.id, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.success, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.username, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.note"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=25"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.10..68.04 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.133..0.133 rows=0 loops=7932)"
"                Inner Unique: true"
"                Hash Cond: (ctl_2.tag_id = ct_2.id)"
"                Buffers: shared hit=777857"
"                ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_2  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1528 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.098 rows=1301 loops=3796)"
"                      Output: ctl_2.id, ctl_2.tag_id, ctl_2.tested_on, ctl_2.success, ctl_2.username, ctl_2.note"
"                      Filter: ctl_2.success"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 56"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=81286"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=23.02..23.02 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=100 loops=7932)"
"                      Output: ct_2.id"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=696571"
"                      ->  Index Scan using cfg_commissioning_tags_idx on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_2  (cost=0.41..23.02 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.049 rows=100 loops=7932)"
"                            Output: ct_2.id"
"                            Index Cond: (((ct_2.type_id)::text = (ct_1.type_id)::text) AND ((ct_2.relative_tag_path)::text = (ct_1.relative_tag_path)::text) AND ((ct_2.tag_source)::text = 'plc'::text))"
"                            Filter: ((ct_2.device_name)::text <> (ct_1.device_name)::text)"
"                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=696571"
"Planning Time: 0.550 ms"
"Execution Time: 1143.359 ms"
```

**EDIT 3**
Replaced covering index on cfg_commissioning_tags:

```
"Sort  (cost=540847.20..540867.03 rows=7932 width=198) (actual time=1152.113..1152.682 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"  Output: ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, (CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE dat_commissioning_test_log.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END)"
"  Sort Key: ct_1.full_path"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2290kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=784891"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=149.19..540333.47 rows=7932 width=198) (actual time=2.016..1115.111 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"        Output: ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN 'true*'::text ELSE CASE dat_commissioning_test_log.success WHEN CASE_TEST_EXPR THEN 'true'::text ELSE 'false'::text END END"
"        Hash Cond: (ct_1.id = dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=784891"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_1  (cost=0.00..426.32 rows=7932 width=140) (actual time=0.014..0.755 rows=7932 loops=1)"
"              Output: ct_1.id, ct_1.full_path, ct_1.device_name, ct_1.device_parent_path, ct_1.added_on, ct_1.relative_tag_path, ct_1.retired_on, ct_1.tag_source, ct_1.type_id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=347"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=139.24..139.24 rows=796 width=35) (actual time=1.613..1.613 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"              Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id"
"              Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 83kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=50"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=85.28..139.24 rows=796 width=35) (actual time=1.117..1.449 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                    Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.note, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id"
"                    Inner Unique: true"
"                    Hash Cond: (dat_commissioning_test_log.id = "ANY_subquery".max)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=50"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1593 width=39) (actual time=0.010..0.100 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"                          Output: dat_commissioning_test_log.id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tag_id, dat_commissioning_test_log.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log.success, dat_commissioning_test_log.username, dat_commissioning_test_log.note"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=82.78..82.78 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=1.103..1.103 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                          Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                          Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 66kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=80.78..82.78 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.798..0.940 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                Group Key: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=48.90..77.23 rows=1417 width=4) (actual time=0.332..0.549 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                      Output: "ANY_subquery".max"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=48.90..63.07 rows=1417 width=8) (actual time=0.331..0.482 rows=1417 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: max(dat_commissioning_test_log_1.id), dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id"
"                                            Group Key: dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=25"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log dat_commissioning_test_log_1  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1593 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.095 rows=1593 loops=1)"
"                                                  Output: dat_commissioning_test_log_1.id, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tag_id, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.tested_on, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.success, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.username, dat_commissioning_test_log_1.note"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=25"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.10..68.04 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.134..0.134 rows=0 loops=7932)"
"                Inner Unique: true"
"                Hash Cond: (ctl_2.tag_id = ct_2.id)"
"                Buffers: shared hit=784494"
"                ->  Seq Scan on public.dat_commissioning_test_log ctl_2  (cost=0.00..40.93 rows=1528 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.098 rows=1301 loops=3796)"
"                      Output: ctl_2.id, ctl_2.tag_id, ctl_2.tested_on, ctl_2.success, ctl_2.username, ctl_2.note"
"                      Filter: ctl_2.success"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 56"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=81286"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=23.02..23.02 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=100 loops=7932)"
"                      Output: ct_2.id"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=703208"
"                      ->  Index Scan using cfg_commissioning_tags_idx on public.cfg_commissioning_tags ct_2  (cost=0.41..23.02 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.049 rows=100 loops=7932)"
"                            Output: ct_2.id"
"                            Index Cond: (((ct_2.type_id)::text = (ct_1.type_id)::text) AND ((ct_2.relative_tag_path)::text = (ct_1.relative_tag_path)::text) AND ((ct_2.tag_source)::text = 'plc'::text))"
"                            Filter: ((ct_2.device_name)::text <> (ct_1.device_name)::text)"
"                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=703208"
"Planning Time: 0.514 ms"
"Execution Time: 1153.156 ms"
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query (in plain text) ? On the db-fiddle it takes just one millisecond, but it's an almost empty database as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added the result to the OP at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need those compound Indexes :

```
CREATE index cfg_commissioning_tags_idx on cfg_commissioning_tags(type_id, relative_tag_path, device_name, tag_source);

CREATE index dat_commissioning_test_log_idx on dat_commissioning_test_log(tag_id, success);
```

You can extend the first Index to take in addition of the columns that are used on the `where` clause and `join`, We can add all the columns that are used on the select (in this case we can add `device_parent_path` to our index), this type of index called `Covering Index`.

Comment: I added these, thanks! It went from 10+s to query down to 1s :) Still a bit slow, but far better than it was.

Comment: I added the explain result after adding these as well

Comment: Try the covering index `CREATE index cfg_commissioning_tags_idx on cfg_commissioning_tags(type_id, relative_tag_path, device_name, tag_source, device_parent_path);`

Comment: Hmm, I removed the previous index and added the new one, and I get about the same result

Comment: The Covering Index is little better, in this exact case could be with no benefits but for sure it is better since the fields of the SELECT are found in the index. so did not have to look in the table to finish the task.

Comment: The "covering" index is not really covering, since it also needs to access the column "id" which is not included in that definition.

Comment: @njminchin Are you sure you created the index dat_commissioning_test_log_idx correctly? I don't see the sense in that index not being used.

Comment: Adding `id` into the cfg_commissioning_tags_idx index increases the query time to 7s. Yep, the index is definitely there for dat_commissioning_test_log_idx